# Install Google Cloud SDK on server

Tags: php, openshift, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Openshift (Linux) to host my web-app. I want to use PHP to upload content to my Google Cloud Storage account.

I've followed the [Installation Instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#linux) for the Cloud Storage SDK, but it seems that `install.sh` wants to write to the root directory (to which I don't have write permissions).

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

Even though it prompts me to choose an installation directory (I choose `/var/lib/openshift/55c011/app-root/data`), into which it successfully un-tars the files, it still tries to access the root directory `/var/lib/openshift/55c011`.

Here is the console output:

```
/var/lib/openshift/55c011/app-root/data/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
WARNING: Could not setup log file in /var/lib/openshift/55c011/.config/gcloud/logs, (Error: Could not create directory [/var/lib/openshift/55c011/.config/gcloud/logs/2016.07.25]: Permission denied.
Please verify that you have permissions to write to the parent directory.)
```

Has anyone out there successfully installed Google Storage SDK on Openshift, or does anyone know how I can stop the installer from trying to write to the root directory?

Comment: It surely looks like a permission issue. try to run the installation from a user account that has proper access rights.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible, there is no user account with write access to that directory. According to the openshift documentation: 'Users do not have root privileges on their gears'. (https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/remote-connection.html)

Comment: You dont have access to `/var/lib/openshift/55c011/`? you should. its your own directory i suppose.

Comment: No, I need root access to write to that directory. `ls -ld` =>
`drwxr-x---. 19 root 55c011 4096 Dec 16  2015 .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the installation scripts, I found a way to override the default config location:

```
export CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
```

This allowed the installation to complete without errors.